# How can I use Entity Framework Code First with an existing MS Access (.accdb) database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I've followed [this MVC 4 tutorial,](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) but I've run into a problem getting the controller to read from my existing database.

I've altered my controller to override the constructor like this:

```
public ItemDBContext()
        : base("dbName")
    {
    }
```

But when I attempt to access the /Items route when debugging, I get this error:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.


Line 19:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 20:         {
Line 21:             return View(db.Items.ToList());
Line 22:         }
```

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="dbName" connectionString="Data Source=C:\dbName.accdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=passWord;" providerName="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"/>
```

I'm not sure exactly where I went wrong. I'm trying to map the model I created to the pre-existing database, but I can't figure out how to do it with MS Access databases.

Comment: what version of access do you have ?

Comment: I actually don't have MS Access; just a database. I'm pretty sure it's 2007, though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this message is that .Net does not know how to open the DB file because you do not have MS-Access installed on the server machine running the ASP.NET code.

You have two options.

Install MS-Access 20007 (it will include the drivers for "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0")
Or download and install the Access DB engine only from here (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: I already had the MS Access 2007 database engine installed. You linked the 2010 version, which I just installed, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Entity Framework Provider for Microsoft Access.

If you want to test with a portable database, i recommend use Sql Server CE 4.0 or SQLite, both have EF provider.

Comment: +1 For more information, see [Can my ASP.NET web application use a Microsoft Access database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database), specifically the part that says "the Jet provider has been superseded by the ACE provider, which specifically disallows use in web applications".